# Current mismatch in digital constant current source

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, constant-current

For an electrochemical etching process I am trying to put together a battery powered, somewhat accurate current source able to provide 1mA to 5mA to a load with a varying resistance. (to be specific, it should be able to switch between 1mA, 2mA and 5mA to a load that is less than a few kΩ.)

The idea I had was to control the current through an NPN transistor using a low-pass filtered PWM signal from a microcontroller:

[image]

The values are chosen based on what I had lying around, making sure that the time constant of the low-pass filter is large enough to reduce the ripple somewhat, and R1 limits the output current to about 6mA. This results in the following simulated output current (red) when the duty cycle (blue) is swept from 0% to 100%:

[image: Output current]

I thought it would then be possible to use one of the analog inputs of the microcontroller to read out the voltage over the current limiting resistor R1 and use that to calculate the current through it according to Ohm's law. Then I could adjust the PWM duty cycle from the microcontroller using simple PI control.

The use of a microcontroller is convenient as I can show the measured current on a display without having to include a complete multimeter in the setup. Additionally it means I can switch between the target currents with a single button rather than having to use something like a potmeter to adjust the current with less precision.

After implementing this circuit though I ran into something unexpected. The PI control works well and quickly settles on the PWM where the calculated current through R1 is equal to the target current. If I use a multimeter to measure the current through R1 this also matches.

However, if I measure the current in series with the load I measure a current that is about 20% to 30% lower for all current settings. I am using a 220Ω load and the 5V microcontroller supply voltage as Vbat for testing. This supply should be sufficient to drive this load according to the previous plot which uses these parameters.

What could be the problem here? Did I overlook anything in the design? Is my multimeter at fault? :)

Thanks for any insights provided.

Comment: Don't quite understand the use of pwm and the whole complexity to get a bad current source instead of using DAC and opamp as it is usually done.

Comment: What would make this current source bad specifically? The analog input of the microcontroller is a DAC. On top of the added benefit of being able to monitor the current. Could you link an example of such a configuration with an opamp and a DAC?

Comment: DAC is Digital To Analog converter, it's an output from MCU that outputs voltage (current setpoint). There are  thousands of current source circuits, google: opamp current source. It makes no sense to use a PWM for such small current, and then sense with ADC, then compute,...the opamp does it all, almost at speed of light, and precise.

Comment: Value of \$V_{BAT}\$? You may not have enough headroom, especially near 5mA. Try a larger voltage and see if 20% 30% error goes away.

Comment: @MarkMar What is the dynamic range of resistance to be driven? What exactly are the voltages you are willing to make available? What does "somewhat accurate" mean? (Accuracy requires traceability to standards. Precision is entirely another thing.) And what is the load, exactly?

Comment: @glen_geek headroom should be enough judging by the simulation at least. I'm currently using the MCU supply voltage of 5V but both the MCU and the load will be powered from a 9V battery.

Comment: @jonk The load is expected to be below $1k\Ohm$. As for the accuracy/precision, I used "somewhat accurate" because there's a good bit of play in the specs. It's mainly important that the current is constant as the load varies slowly and that it's well known so that the results can be reproduced. Ripple is less important. If it's got a deviation in the order of 1% from the specified values that would suffice.

Comment: @MarkMar The load helps. This means 1-5V is your dynamic range of voltage (assuming this isn't a bipolar need.) Since you want reproducible results, this implies a product (more than one will be built and validated.) And this strongly suggests *accuracy*, which means traceable-to-standards, dealing with wide operating temperature ranges, and periodic re-calibration to those standards over time. 1% *traceable accuracy* for current is doable. But not slapped together without careful thinking. The variation allowance seems to argue the other way. Also, what's the actual load? It matters, I think.

Comment: @jonk It's not for a product, it's to be used in a small setup for electrochemical etching, so the load is a pcb and a fairly conductive solution. It has to be reproducible so that the results of a few batches are comparable. It is indeed accuracy that is important here.

Comment: @Marko Buršič Oh right, I confused the two. The main reason I'm using an MCU now is because it's convenient to switch between the three accurately required currents without having to use a pot. Unfortunately I don't have a microcontroller with a DAC at hand hence why I used the PWM output. Ordering an IC with a DAC might be an option. An alternative would be to switch between a few different resistor values but then I would not be able to finetune it unless I use a pot for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where the problem is. Your base current in driving the BJT transistor into saturation  is going to be a significant part of the current flowing through the emitter resistor. So, what you measure across that emitter sense resistor is true load current plus base current. If you chose a linear circuit using an opamp, the base current would be much less (maybe 0.5% instead of 5%).

You mention a deficit of 20% to 30% and that doesn't surprise me either.

After discussion with the op on this and that, I suggested that emitter and collector pins of the transistor be rechecked because if he had placed the transistor incorrectly in the circuit, it would still work but with a significantly reduced beta value. This seems to be what actually happened.

So, when a person (like me) diagnoses a transistor saturation problem based on apparently poor beta (too much base current), it isn't wise to jump all over my answer and down-vote it because it might not appear to fit your limited scope of knowledge. In doing so you totally run the risk of the op not getting the help they truly deserve. Take note.

Comment: BC547 Hfe is a min of 100, so base current is not the reason the output current is deviant. The maximum base current would be about 2uA.

Comment: That's absolute rubbish when you consider transistor saturation values.

Comment: The transistor only tends toward saturation when the op has the current range of the multimeter in series. So you whole answer is wrong. At no point could you ever have 20-30% of the output current flowing in the base.

Comment: This answer seems to be right, measuring the base current it is indeed about 10% of the emitter current. However, I am not certain what could be causing it. Could it be the lowpass? I do not expect the transistor to go into saturation until I reach the current limit somewhere above 6mA. 

I could use an Opamp in this configuration but it seems to me that there would still be the same base current, at least if I keep the same feedback measuring the current through R1. I could technically also measure the voltage across the load and control the input voltage based on that.

Comment: I expect that the transistor is going into saturation but have no facilities around me to verify that. You need to look at Vce and decide whether this is happening or not. It may be that the filtering on the base signal is not sufficient to prevent base overdrive at the peak of the filtered signal and that may be happening. I have no facility to help further because I'm in a hospital (not mental I might add lol)

Comment: When supplying 1mA I measure Vc = 4.8V, Vb = 1.2V, and Ve = 0.56V wrt ground, "just like the simulations". So that should not be in saturation. Filtering should be sufficient too for the 490Hz PWM signal. I'll have to play around with some opamps and see how things change. 

Also hope you'll get out of there soon! (and that the questions here won't get you into a mental hospital either) :)

Comment: @MarkMarketing The base current is in microamps, if you are measuring the current in R2 that is quite different, since there you will measure the current to charge/discharge  C1. Since as you've already seen Q1 is not saturated the base current is define by the HFE of the transistor.

Comment: @JackCreasey I put the meter in between the node to which both the cap and resistor are connected and the transistor base. Here I measured >.1mA at 1mA emitter current. This seems to check out as I measure >.9mA collector current. odd

Comment: @mark marketing double check emitter and collector are not swapped over.

Comment: Bjt transistors will work upside down but beta will be a fraction of that seen with the proper connection of collector and emitter.

Comment: @Andy aka You can't make this up... Not swapping those certainly improves things, yeah, you end up with a few uA. I'm certain I double checked this. Must've put it back in wrong when changing the circuit. Perhaps the mental hospital is something for me. :)
Anyhow this means that once I add an opamp and DAC things should work very well, thanks again.

Comment: Good man. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: @Andyaka ..Your answer is still wrong. The transistor was never in saturation, and clearly could never be. The fact the OP had the transistor connected backward would have been discovered eventually. "jumping all over your answer" is just a cop out, you still have not corrected your poor initial assumptions.

Comment: You were totally wrong to down-vote me Jack creasey and you need to stop jumping in feet first the minute someone says something that doesn't tally with your train of thought.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple current source with opamp + yours transistor + yours shunt resistor.

[image]

The blue line is the setpoint (Iset=V/548) and the green line is the current through the load resistor.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! 

With a setup like this I would still need to provide the three desired voltages at the positive opamp terminal corresponding to the target currents. 

If I want to accurately set these input voltage of the positive opamp terminal without having to precisely turn a knob and looking at a current meter, should I still be using an MCU sensing the voltage over the shunt resistor (or the voltage before and after the load, for that matter)? Or is there a better alternative I'm not considering?

Comment: @MarkMarketing This circuit uses an op-amp. In this configuration, it wants to keep the voltage at its - positive the same as is + pin voltage. It does this by having an high gain and a "slow" (In the megahertz range) skew rate. If you a DAC to input a voltage of 1V into the + pin, the circuit will increase the current until the voltage drop over R1 equals 1V, and since we know its a 548 resistor, we can us ohms law to calculate that this means 1.82mA over this resistor, and about 1.81mA is left after we subtract the transistors base current. (assuming gain around 100).

Comment: @Ferrybig I understand that. But there may be a difference between the calculated current for a given input voltage and the actual current, depending on e.g. temperature changes or if the load ends up higher than expected. Either way there will probably need to be a way to finetune the input voltage and to measure the resulting current. Doing that with the MCU seems convenient.

Comment: @MarkMarketing This circuit by Marko automatically compensates for any changes in rload. Even in a short circuit the current stays the same. For the sense resistor, you could sense, it, but its voltage should always match your control voltage, so you don't get any information out of it. If the temperature of the sense resistor is important, mount it in a fixed temperature box. (note that your original circuit also has problems with the resistors changing resistance as their temperature changes) Use kelvin sense to measure the exact resistor value, and use that as your calibration

Comment: @ferrybig With a too high load I meant the load going above that what Vbat can supply in this configuration. Ideally it would be possible to see if the circuit fails to supply the current. I'll have to check if that's convenient across R1 since if Q2 goes into saturation the current through R3 will decrease but that through R1 will keep increasing slightly. It might be more convenient to add a small sensing resistor in series with R3 then.

Comment: You're right about the sense resistor. I think I shouldn't be too afraid of changes in the resistor temperatures since the currents are small and the environment it will be used in is climate controlled. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkMarketing The circuit provides better accuracy then you could measure it with ADC, not to mention the transient response.  The accuracy depends on voltage reference accuracy and the shunt resistor temperature stability.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the circuit you built, there are a couple of problems with both the design and performing measurements on it.

The good:
The circuit as shown would operate.

- With a 220 Ohm load resistor (R3), to get 5mA load current you will drop 1.1 volts across the load resistor (ignoring the actual plating load you want to drive). The voltage across the 558 Ohm (R1) would be 2.79V and represent approximately 55% duty cycle of your PWM. The transistor is operating as an Emitter follower (wrt Base drive) and is nowhere close to any saturation effects (VCE is about 1.1V).
- You don't need to have R1 at all, the collector current is limited by the configuration, you should remove it.

The bad:

- Assuming your input PWM is 0-5V, you can't get more than 4.3V on R1. This gives a maximum current of about 7.7mA max at 100% duty cycle (5VDC on Q2 Base).
- At 7.7mA through the load resistor (R3) you need to drop 1.69V. Unfortunately with only a 5V supply you cannot provide this current.
  You need at least 4.3 + 1.69 = 6V.
  I'd suggest that you need at least 9V to ensure you have sufficient voltage to drive your plating load. If you remove R1 you reduce the supply voltage requirement, but I'd suggest you may want at least 2-4V available across the plating terminals.
- At low PWM duty cycle you have a problem since to produce any current through Q2 collector you need about 0.7V. So for currents in the microamp range you need a PWM duty cycle of (0.7/5) * 100 = 14% duty cycle. Since you suggest you need plating currents in the 1-5mA range this means you only use duty cycles from about 25% through to 70% or about 40% of the PWM range available. Depending on the resolution of your PWM this may be a constraint.
- Since you know that the 5V supply is not sufficient for the higher current flows, its likely that any measurement you make with a multimeter could be flawed by the Burden voltage of the current ranges. The Burden voltage for multimeters may vary from 2mV/mA through to 20mV/mA depending on your meter. At 20mV/mA it is the same as putting an additional 20 Ohms in series with your load.

**Update:**
Added a very simple simulation (Square wave input ie 50% duty cycle) where the transistor can never be in saturation. You can see from this that the HFE of the BC547B is around 300. The Emitter current about 3.2mA and the Base current about 10uA.
You don't even need to run the simulator ...if you open the schematic and hover over Q1 it will describe the DC conditions and show the Base, Emitter and Collector currents/voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhbPos.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am aware the shunt resistor is not needed, but since I only need to go up to 5mA I expected that scaling the current down would improve the resolution following from the limited resolution at the pwm input. I'm missing though how the effects you describe would result in the decrease in measured current even at a low current like 1mA. Even at 5V this should easily drive the 220 Ohm and the current meter. This is still my main problem. Especially since I don't see this in the Sims either